# Eu consigo usar o método .sort() (flutter) pra ordenar uma lista de objetos com mais de 1 propriedade?

Tags: flutter, dart

*Estou fazendo uma tabela de classificação de times, então pensei em usar o metodo .sort() pra ordenar usando as propriedade da classe:*

```
 TeamsScore {
          final int points;
          final int matches;
          final int victories;
          final int drawOrTie;
          final int defeats;
          final int goals;
          final int ownGoal;
          final int yellowCard;
          final int redCard;
          final int goalBalance;
}
```

*Criei a class TeamScoreData pra criar uma lista de times*

```
class TeamScoreData {
  static List<TeamsScore> teamstable = [
    TeamsScore(
      name: 'INTERNACIONAL',
      shield: 'assets/images/logoLigaSmall.png',
      points: 1,
      matches: 2,
      victories: 3,
      drawOrTie: 4,
      defeats: 5,
      goals: 6,
      ownGoal: 7,
      yellowCard: 8,
      redCard: 9,
      goalBalance: 10,
    ), 
    TeamsScore(
      name: 'Olimpia',
      shield: 'assets/images/logoLigaSmall.png',
      points: 2,
      matches: 3,
      victories: 3,
      drawOrTie: 3,
      defeats: 3,
      goals: 3,
      ownGoal: 3,
      yellowCard: 3,
      redCard: 3,
      goalBalance: 3,
    ),
```

*E agora quero ordenar os times de acordo com cada propriedade sendo point é a mais importante e a goalBalance a menos importante.*
Para isso eu utilizei o mnétodo .sort() no entanto do modo que fiz só analisa uma propriedade **Gostaria de saber se há um forma de ordenar utilizando mais propriedades além da points**

```
 class _TableTeamsState extends State<TableTeams> {
     final teamstable = TeamScoreData.teamstable;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            teamstable.sort(
              (teamB, teamA) => teamA.points.compareTo(teamB.points));
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkWMC.png)

Comment: Fala Emerson, bem vindo ao site. Se você puder editar sua pergunta e adicionar melhor o que você quer, ajudaria. Por exemplo, quando se ordena entre duas propriedades, uma delas precisará ter a preferência. Outra coisa que ajudaria seria mostrar o quê você já tentou e o que deu de errado. Isto é, se comportou de uma maneira diferente do que você queria? Deu algum erro? Qual? Um abraço e boa sorte.

Comment: Compreendi!! Irei melhorar muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método [sort](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.7/dart-core/List/sort.html) recebe como parâmetro uma função de comparação. Esse método vai usar essa função de comparação para saber como ordenar os elementos, isto é, saber qual vem depois de qual.

Você pode escolher a função que você quiser, e inclusive você já fez isso em seu exemplo. A função que você passa é uma que recebe dois times e retorna a comparação entre a propriedade `points` de cada um.

Isso foi feito por meio do método [compareTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/compareTo.html). Esse método é um método de comparação, que é o que o método `sort` espera.

Uma [função de comparação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Comparator.html) é uma função que retorna:

- um inteiro negativo se o primeiro item é menor que o segundo;
- um inteiro posítivo se o primeiro item é maior que o segundo;
- zero se os dois itens são iguais;

Portanto, quando você chama o método `sort`, você pode criar a função que você quiser. Desde que você respeite as regras de retorno. Você não precisa usar um método pronto. Por exemplo:

```dart
teamstable.sort((teamB, teamA) {
    int comparacaoPontos = teamA.points.compareTo(teamB.points);
    int comparacaoGoals = teamA.goalBalance.compareTo(teamB.goalBalance);
    
    if (comparacaoPontos != 0) {
      return comparacaoPontos;
    } 
    // Caso uma comparação retorne 0, significa que eles são iguais, 
    // logo devemos retornar a comparação envolvendo a segunda propriedade.
    return comparacaoGoals;
  });
```

O que deve ter o retorno esperado. Isto é, ordena baseado na propriedade `points`, e nos casos de empate, o desempate é feito baseado na propriedade `goalBalance`.

Comment: Compreendi!! Na verdade agora fez tudo o sentido. Agora consigo prossegir com o projeto. Muito obrigado